# Decreasing 2 counters while waiting inbetween

Tags: android

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    this.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.queue);
    overridePendingTransition(0,0);

    final TextView encounter = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.output);
    Button b1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.start);

    int counterA = 100;
    int counterB = 100;

    encounter.setText("Counter A : " + Integer.toString(counterA) + "\nCounter B : " + Integer.toString(counterB));

    b1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

        }
    });
}
```

Hi, I am more or less new to android. I am trying to get a little simulation running with 2 counters and a textView where the current values of the counters are displayed.

Now when I press a button I want to decrease the value by 10 alternating on counter A and counter B until one hits 0, and between every decrease I want to wait 1 second and update the textView with the new Value.

I tryed some stuff with threads, but all I got was that the values get decreased, but the textView doesn't update until the end (when one hits 0).

Could someone help me?

Comment: you have to set this piece : `encounter.setText("Counter A : ")` inside your `onClick`, otherwise the updated values after 1 sec will not be displayed in txtView. Also do `thread.sleep(1000)` for a second of delay .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a Handler.

```
     Handler m_handler;
     Runnable m_handlerTask ;
     TextView encounter;
     int countA=100,countB=100;
```

In your onCreate

```
     encounter = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.output);
     m_handler = new Handler();
```

On button Click

```
     m_handlerTask = new Runnable()
     {
         @Override 
         public void run() { 
            if(countA>=0 && countB>=0)
            {     
            encounter.setText("Count A ="+countA+" "+"Count B ="+countB);
            countA=countA-10;
            countB=countB-10;
            }
            else
            {
                m_handler.removeCallbacks(m_handlerTask);
            } 
              m_handler.postDelayed(m_handlerTask, 1000);    

         }
    };
    m_handlerTask.run();
```

Answer (score 1):

Use the AsyncTask class instead of traditional Threads and the method [onProgressUpdate](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html) which can refresh the UI (invoked in the UI Thread).

Note : AsyncTask must be subclassed to be used.

Use `publishProgress` inside `doInBackground` to trigger `onProgressUpdate` :

```
publishProgress(counter1, counte2);
```

Then define what onProgressUpdate must do :

```
protected void onProgressUpdate(Integer... counters) {
    // Update UI using counters[0] and counters[1] // Update the TextView
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use the [CountDownTimer](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/CountDownTimer.html) class.

Here's an example :

```
new CountDownTimer(30000, 1000) {

             public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
                 tv.setText("seconds remaining: " + millisUntilFinished / 1000);
             }

             public void onFinish() {
                 tv.setText("done!");
             }
          }.start();
```

Here's the parameters for the contructor :

30000 - The number of millis in the future from the call to `start()` until the countdown is done and `onFinish()` is called.
1000 - The interval along the way to receive `onTick(long)` callbacks.

Comment: @downvoter Could you explain ? I used this to update my textView and it works well.

Comment: Yes, a lot of people down vote answers without explaining why it was down voted.  I have been a victim of this as well, countless times..feel your pain..up voted .:) cheers .

Comment: @TheDarkKnight Yes.... I always accept downvote when they are explained. Some people downvote and actually they don't know if the answer is working. If something is wrong, I prefer that he comments.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't tested this but it should work, the boolean changes the counter to be decreased and the handler, makes it sleep for 1000 ms.

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    this.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.queue);
    overridePendingTransition(0,0);

    final TextView encounter = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.output);
    Button b1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.start);

    int counterA = 100;
    int counterB = 100;
    boolean countera=true;


    encounter.setText("Counter A : " + Integer.toString(counterA) + "\nCounter B : " + 

    Integer.toString(counterB));
    b1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
      //switch counters
         if(countera){
          countera=false;
          countera-=10;
        }else{
          counterb-=10;
          coutnera=true;
         }
        }
  Handler h = new Handler(); 
  h.postDelayed(new Runnable() { 
     public void run() { 
          encounter.setText("Counter A : " + Integer.toString(counterA) + "\nCounter B  : " + Integer.toString(counterB));
     } 
}, 1000); 
    });
}
```